# Unable to close a kotlin channel

Tags: kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I am trying to understand why a kotlin channel is not closed after I call close on it, below a basic code:

```
@Test
fun `test channel`() = runBlocking {
    val buffer = Channel<Int>(3)
    val job = launch {
        launch {
            buffer.send(1)
            delay(1000)
            buffer.send(2)
            delay(1000)
            buffer.send(3)
            delay(1000)
            buffer.close()
        }

        launch {
            while (!buffer.isClosedForReceive) {
                println("isClosed " + buffer.isClosedForReceive)
                delay(5000)
            }
        }
    }

    job.join()
}
```

I have kotlin coroutines, 1st sends an int every second 3 times and then close it and the 2nd one check if the channel has been closed or not

The 2nd coroutine do never exist, and keep displaying:

```
isClosed false
isClosed false
isClosed false
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation for [close()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-send-channel/close.html) says, the channel is immediately closed only for sending, but it is closed for receiving after consuming all its items:

> Immediately after invocation of this function, isClosedForSend starts returning true. However, isClosedForReceive on the side of ReceiveChannel starts returning true only after all previously sent elements are received.

You don't consume items from the channel, so it always contains items that still wait to be consumed. This is why it never closes for receiving.